# Initializing generic type inside generic class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types, typescript-class

I want to initialize a generic class variable inside a generic class using a generic type, but I can't figure out if there is a way to do this.

Initializing with types works fine, it doesn't seem like it work with generics though.

```
type EventCallback<I, O> = (event: I) => O;

type ListenerList<K extends string | symbol | number, I, O, V extends EventCallback<I, O>> = {
    [T in K]: V[];
};

const test: ListenerList<string, string, string, (event: any) => any> = {}; // Works fine

export default class EventProcesser<
  K extends string | symbol | number,
  I,
  O,
  V extends EventCallback<I, O>
> {
  private listeners: ListenerList<K, I, O, V> = {}; // Error :(
}
```

I get the following error `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ListenerList<K, I, O, V>'`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `ListenerList` is assuming, that the object has at least one property. Adding a questionmark behind the `[T in K]` you are safe to go, because you are telling typescript, that there is at least zero properties in the object.

Comment: Thanks, this also works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`K` can be a string literal type, so `EventProcesser<'prop', ..>` is valid meaning that `listeners` must have property named `prop`. This means that your default will not be valid for any `K` passed in as it should be.

You can use `Partial` to let the compiler know that no properties will be required:

```
type EventCallback<I, O> = (event: I) => O;

type ListenerList<K extends string | symbol | number, I, O, V extends EventCallback<I, O>> = {
    [T in K]: V[];
};

const test: ListenerList<string, string, string, (event: any) => any> = {}; // Works fine

export default class EventProcesser<
    K extends string | symbol | number,
    I,
    O,
    V extends EventCallback<I, O>
    > {
    private listeners: Partial<ListenerList<K, I, O, V>> = {}; // ok
}
```