# Pushing generic value on to generic list in a generic class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types, typescript-class

I am trying to push a generic object onto a list of generic objects inside a generic class.

It's probably just something with the semantics, but I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
type EventCallback<I, O> = (event: I) => O;

type ListenerList<K extends string | symbol | number, I, O, V extends EventCallback<I, O>> = {
    [T in K]?: V[];
};

const test: ListenerList<string, string, string, (event: any) => any> = {
   test : [],
};

const key = 'test';
test[key]!.push((event: string) => 'Hello ' + event); // Works fine

export default class EventProcesser<
  K extends string | symbol | number,
  I,
  O,
  V extends EventCallback<I, O>
> {
  private listeners: ListenerList<K, I, O, V> = {};

  public on(target: K, callback: V): void {
    this.listeners[target].push(callback); // Error
  }
}
```

If I define the type, it works, but it doesn't feel like a good solution to the problem:

```
...
   (this.listeners[target] as V[]).push(callback) // Works
...
```

The error I get, says the following: `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'ListenerList<K, I, O, V>[K]'`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I needed to add `!` to the `listeners` variable, as it is not certain that `listeners` have any keys at all. The solution is therefore to do the follow instead:

```
   this.listeners[target]!.push(callback) // Works
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove optional keys from

```
type ListenerList<K extends string | symbol | number, I, O, V extends EventCallback<I, O>> = { [T in K]?: V[] };
```

=>

```
type ListenerList<K extends string | symbol | number, I, O, V extends EventCallback<I, O>> = { [T in K]: V[] };
```

Comment: That is also a solution, but will cause this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222509/initializing-generic-type-inside-generic-class-in-typescript